# Update Sqlite Tuple from tkinter entry

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have this current code which writes data into entry boxes. I am trying to create a feature which selects what is in the boxes and updates the record in the table, Trainers. This is the current code:

```
 def Update(self):

    global Record
    global Name
    global TrainerID
    global Postcode
    global Age
    global Gender
    global Password

    (Name, TrainerID, Postcode, Age, Gender, Password) = tuple(Record)

    Name = self.ent_Name.get()
    TrainerID = self.ent_TrainerID.get()
    Postcode = self.ent_Postcode.get()
    Age = self.ent_Age.get()
    Gender = self.ent_Gender.get()
    Password = self.ent_Password.get()

    List = [Name, TrainerID, Postcode, Age, Gender, Password]

    self.cur.execute("UPDATE Trainers SET Name=?, TrainerID=?, Postcode=?,Age,=? Gender=?, Password=?",((Name,) (TrainerID,) (Postcode,) (Age,) (Gender,) (Password,)))
```

This is the error:

`File "E:\Program\TrainerAccounts.py", line 194, in Update
    self.cur.execute("UPDATE Trainers SET Name=?, TrainerID=?, Postcode=?,Age,=? Gender=?, Password=?",((Name,) (TrainerID,) (Postcode,) (Age,) (Gender,) (Password,)))
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`

Comment: First of all, what is the error you get? have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format

Comment: You've told us what you want, but haven't explained what problem you're having. Is this code throwing an error? Is it storing the wrong data?

Comment: It isn't updating the record in the database, the error is: `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error`

Comment: what you have the is trying to update only one record `TrainerID=?` but you several db columns you want to update `(Name, TrainerID, Postcode, Age, Gender, Password)`

Comment: create a minimal code to debug it and also do want to update only `TrainerID`  or all the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post minimal code am assuming this what you want to update for the `TrainerID`

```
 self.cur.execute("UPDATE Trainers WHERE TrainerID=?",(TrainerID),)
```

if you want to update all the record do this

```
 self.cur.execute("UPDATE Trainers SET Name=?, TrainerID=?, Postcode=?, Age=?, Gender=?, Password=?",(Name, TrainerID, Postcode, Age, Gender, Password)
```

Comment: you can comment when you are facing challenges.

Comment: HI, I copied the code for all the record and it came up with this error: `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error`

Comment: It looks like your comma is missplaced. Shouldn't it be `(TrainerID,)` instead of `(TrainerID),`?

Comment: That has resulted in the error `TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`

Comment: can you paste what you have in that line as comment with this it hard to answer

Comment: check my edit on this `self.cur.execute("UPDATE Trainers SET Name=?, TrainerID=?, Postcode=?, Age=? Gender=?, Password=?",(Name, TrainerID, Postcode, Age, Gender, Password)`

Comment: That creates `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "Gender": syntax error`

Comment: check it i forgot to bring comma after Age, Gender